# Php cookie only set for 1 second?

Tags: php, cookies

Maybe there is a better way around having to use a cookie. But i want to set in my php something to tell the user an error but only have it come on once, if they refresh the page i do no want it there anymore.

```
$time = (1000);
setcookie("msgtype", $type, time() + ($time), '/');
setcookie("msg", $message, time() + ($time), '/');
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

So for some reason, if i output the $_cookie directly after it still won't display this cookie.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, when showing the error clear the cookie, rather than having it set for 1 second, so that when it refreshes next time & checks for the cookie it won't be there and so would not display any error.

`Or a better option would be using sessions.`

Comment: yeah, when using sessions set the expire time to infinite(large value) and destroy the cookie when its task is over.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to use cookies for this, using SESSION sounds reasonable.

```
$_SESSION['error'] = 'soem message';
//Use it when you need and simply remove it afterwards
echo $_SESSION['error'];
unset($_SESSION['error']);
```

Comment: ye, i wanted this time. I originally had it as 1, 1 millisecond as it would be processed in the same script. But for trouble shooting i put it to 1000

Comment: thanks very much, grr what a waste of time :p Just added the unset on the page itself instead of trying to do it cleverly.

Answer (score 0):

In you example i will use SESSIONs

example of set:

```
session_start()
$_SESSION['error'] = 1;
```

when you will display an error use this :)

```
unset($_SESSION['error'];
```

or

```
$_SESSION['error'] = 0;
```

it will depend on usage :)